PyQt/PySide В Spinbox застревают события
Если строку layout.addWidget(sb) закомментировать, то виджет ловит события  (в данном случае события клавиатуры). 
Если строку оставить то нет.
Мне нужен и спинбокс и события клавиатуры.
import sys
import PySide6.QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300,300)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        w = QWidget()
        sb = QSpinBox()
        sb.setRange(-10,10)
        layout.addWidget(w)
        #layout.addWidget(sb)                                 # ?!
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def eventFilter(self, watched: QObject, event: QEvent):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_S:
                print("__S__")
                return True
            elif event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_A:
                print("__A__")
                return True
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


QSpinBox перехватывает нажатие клавиш. Попробуйте создать подкласс SpinBox() и в нем переопределить метод keyPressEvent():
import sys
'''
import PySide6.QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SpinBox(QSpinBox):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == Qt.Key.Key_S:
            print("__S__")
            self.window().label.setText("S")
        elif key == Qt.Key.Key_A:
            print("__A__")
            self.window().label.setText("A")
        else:
            self.window().label.clear()
            return super().keyPressEvent(event)             # !!! +++
 
 
class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        self.w = QWidget()  
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{color: #D98C00; font: 20pt}")
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout(self.w)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.label)
        
        sb = SpinBox(self)                                        # +
        sb.setRange(-10, 10)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.w)
        layout.addWidget(sb)          
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == Qt.Key.Key_S:
            print("__S__")     
            self.label.setText("S")
        elif key == Qt.Key.Key_A:
            print("__A__")        
            self.label.setText("A")
        else:
            self.label.clear()
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.resize(300, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



Интересное решение.
